# Zip every element of list A with every element of list B - best "pythonie" way of doing this

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists which I want to zip

List A:

```
["hello ", "world "]
```

List B:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

I want to zip the elements in the lists like so:

```
[("hello","one")
("hello","two")
("hello","three")
("world","one")
("world","two")
("world","three")]
```

Obviously, I can use a double for loop and append the elements but I am wondering what would be a good pythonie way of doing this?

Comment: The concept you are describing is the "[Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)" and can be achieved using `itertools.product` as shown in the above link.

Comment: That's the word I was looking for... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a perfect use-case for `itertools.product`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(['hello', 'world'], ['one', 'two', 'three']))
[('hello', 'one'), ('hello', 'two'), ('hello', 'three'), ('world', 'one'), ('world', 'two'), ('world', 'three')]
```

Comment: Yep. That's what I was looking for. Cartesian product, as @CoryKramer mentioned.